# How come apply on multiple columns in dataframe does not work?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

I am trying to remove '$' sign and convert value to a float for multiple columns in a dataframe.

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
   policy_status    sum_assured    premium      riders      premium_plus
0        A           1252000 $      1500 $        1.0         1100 $
1        A           1072000 $      2200 $        2.0         1600 $
2        A           1274000 $      1700 $        2.0         1300 $
3        A           1720000 $      2900 $        1.0         1400 $
4        A           1360000 $      1700 $        3.0         1400 $
```

I have this function:

```
def transform_amount(x):
    x=x.replace('$','')
    x=float(x)
    return x
```

when I do this:

```
policy[['sum_assured','premium','premium_plus']]=policy[['sum_assured','premium','premium_plus']].apply(transform_amount)
```

the following error occured:

```
TypeError: ("cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>", 'occurred at index sum_assured')
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If need working elementwise use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
cols = ['sum_assured','policy_premium','rider_premium']
policy[cols]=policy[cols]].applymap(transform_amount)
```

Better is use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex=True`, but first escape `$` because special regex value and convert columns to floats:

```
cols = ['sum_assured','premium','premium_plus']
policy[cols]=policy[cols].replace('\$','', regex=True).astype(float)
print (policy)
  policy_status  sum_assured  premium  riders  premium_plus
0             A    1252000.0   1500.0     1.0        1100.0
1             A    1072000.0   2200.0     2.0        1600.0
2             A    1274000.0   1700.0     2.0        1300.0
3             A    1720000.0   2900.0     1.0        1400.0
4             A    1360000.0   1700.0     3.0        1400.0
```